# Application of Markov chain in problem relating to the limiting distribution of insurance discounts

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains

The setup we have is that an insurance company offers 4 levels of no-claims discount. We have the 0% discount, 10% discount, 20% discount and 30% discount. New customers start with 0% discount. For every year that a customer does not make an insurance claim, they progress onto the next level of discount, progressing no further forward once they reach state 4, the 30% discount. If at any time they make a claim over a year, the next year their discount is set back to $0$%. A customer has probability $p$ of making an insurance claim in any one year. Clearly we can model this as a discrete time Markov chain, I believe the matrix of transition probabilities should look like this:
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
p & 1-p & 0&0\\
p & 0 & 1-p&0\\
p&0 &0 &1-p \\
p&0 &0 &1-p  
\end{pmatrix} $$

We would like to find the limiting distribution for this Markov chain. Now clearly, this chain is regular so it must have a limiting distribution, $\underline{w}$. We also have that this limiting distribution is the same as the unique equilibrium distribution. To find the limiting distribution we need to solve $$\underline{w}P = \underline{w}$$
The problem that I am facing at this point is that when I try to solve this, I only get the trivial solution. Can anyone offer some insight?

EDIT: In response to a comment, when trying to solve the above equation I did this:
$$\begin{pmatrix}w_1&w_2&w_3&w_4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}p & 1-p & 0&0\\
p & 0 & 1-p&0\\
p&0 &0 &1-p \\
p&0 &0 &1-p  
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}w_1&w_2&w_3&w_4 \end{pmatrix}$$
This leads to the following system of linear equation:
$$pw_1 +pw_2+pw_3+pw_4=w_1 $$
$$w_1(1-p) = w_2 $$
$$w_2(1-p) = w_3 $$
$$w_3(1-p)+w_4(1-p)=w_4 $$
From here I try to use Gauss-Jordan elimination but this doesn't seem to provide any solution other than the trivial solution. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Let me try this again.  Forget the $w$ for now.  You need to develop a basis for $\ker (I-P^T )$. (It's one dimensional so it should be easy.) You can use row reduction or QR factorization or whatever technique you like.

Comment: $\mathbf w^T P = \mathbf w^T \iff P^T\mathbf w  = \mathbf w = I \mathbf w \iff \big(I-P^T\big)\mathbf w =\mathbf 0\iff \mathbf w \in \ker \big(I-P^T\big)$ .  It sounds like you need to re-visit an intro to linear algebra text.

Comment: @SergioTachinko . This is not how MSE works. You edited a two-month old question that was about "Application of Markov chain in problem relating to the limiting distribution of insurance discounts" thereby invalidating my answer below. What has this question to do with this ? You should start a new question.

Comment: That question was already [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581150/how-do-we-find-fracdd-underlinexb-underlinex).

Comment: Do not vandalize your question by completely rewriting it.  This is rude to the person who took the time to answer your question, and rude to the larger community which might find the question and answer helpful.  If you have a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top to post it.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of $I-P^\top$ is up to a minus sign the
determinant of
$$\begin{pmatrix}
p-1 & 1-p & 0&0\\
p & -1 & 1-p&0\\
p&0 &-1 &1-p \\
p&0 &0 &-p  
\end{pmatrix} $$
which is zero.
The vector
$$
\underline{w}=\begin{pmatrix}p\\p(1-p)\\p(1-p)^2\\(1-p)^3\end{pmatrix}
$$
is an eigenvector of $P^\top$ with eigenvalue one. Since the sum of its elements is also one  $\underline{w}$ is an invariant distribution.

Comment: The matrix $P$ looks totally correct but I was mistaken yesterday. Please check my solution.

Comment: All your equations in OP can equivalently be written as $\underline{w}P=\underline{w}$ which is the definition of an invariant distribution. Transposing this equation brings it into a form we see in linear algebra $P^\top\underline{w}^\top=\underline{w}^\top$. Of what matrix is $\underline{w}^\top$ an eigenvector ?