# How do we find $\frac{d}{d \underline{x}}(B \underline{x})$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

How do we find $\frac{d}{d \underline{x}}(B \underline{x})$ where $B$ is a matrix of constants? I am aware that there is a result stating that $$\frac{d}{d \underline{x}}(\underline{x}^TB)=B $$ but I am unsure of how this fact could be used to solve the problem in my question. How would I approach this problem?

Comment: The derivative is linear, so $\frac d{dy}ay=a$ with a constant $a$

Comment: Consider transposing and using what you know

Comment: @jro We have $\underline{x}^TB = (B^T \underline{x})^T$. So could the answer just be $B^T$?

Comment: @HungaryGoose Yes, but there is a subtlety here: For better harmony with linear algebra, in defining the total differential of a map $f: ℝ^n → ℝ^m$, one usually makes a choice whether to treat  $ℝ^m $ as consisting of row or of column vectors. If one goes with row vectors and defines the total derivative such that the row-vector valued map $ x ↦ x^T B $ has derivative $B$, then $x ↦ Bx$ would be rewritten as $ x ↦ x^T B^T $ (to get row-vector valued output), which then by the above rule has derivative $B^T$.

Comment: @HungaryGoose I'd like to add: the more widespread convention is to treat elements of $ ℝ^n$, $ ℝ^m $ etc. as column vectors and maps as column vector valued. The derivative is then defined such that $\frac{d}{dx}Bx= B$. Then $ x ↦ x^T B$ would be recast as $x ↦ B^T x$ which would have derivative $B^T$. See e.g. the Wikipedia entry on the total derivative and the Jacobian matrix for details.